# Placing gatsby-plugin-transition-link into gatsby.config file crashes the entire website

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to use gatsby-plugin-transition-link into my project, but whenever I place this into my `gatsby.config` file, my entire website doesn't function (I just see a blank, white page). I inserted it like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`,
    [... other plugins etc.]
  ]
}
```

When I remove the plugin from the config file, my website functions again, but I don't have custom routing animations. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: did you make sure to install the plugin and any additional required dependencies? `npm i -D gatsby-plugin-transition-link`

Comment: I used `yarn` instead of `npm` does that make a difference?

Comment: no it doesn't matter if you use yarn or npm. just do `yarn add -D gatsby-plugin-transition-link`

Comment: `yarn add -D` is used for adding 'devDependencies'. Only use -D for packages not used in production.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to run any special commands. Yarn automatically installs dependencies. Refer to the docs and make sure you've done everything correctly.

https://transitionlink.tylerbarnes.ca/docs/installation/

Maybe list the other plugins you're using and if you are using some kind of  layout plugin like gatsby-plugin-layout you don't need it as transition link replaces it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that none of your layout elements have their positions set to absolute.